# react native - how to get thumbnail uri for camera roll videos

Tags: video, react-native, thumbnails, mediastore, camera-roll

I need a way of displaying thumbnails for CameraRoll videos on the react native side, I solved the android side by adding thumbnail uri to CameraRoll result. Now is there any way on the iOS that I could:

1. get the thumbnail uri (not base64) for the videos.
2. or display the thumbnail on a Image with the video uri.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions that ask us to recommend a library, software package, book, etc- are off topic for SO because they attract opinionated answers and spam. Please edit your question to include what you've tried, as well as a more specific problem that we might be able to help you with.

Comment: Updated description.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Video
      ref={videoPlayer => (this.videoPlayer = videoPlayer)}
      source={{ uri: video.uri }}
      style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
      onLoad={() => {
        this.videoPlayer.seek(2);
      }}
      paused
    />
```

I user seek to take frame on second second.

Comment: welcome to SO:-) it's better to explain why this snippet solves the problem